# duplicating last column of 3d numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array

I have the following numpy 3d array, in which I need to duplicate the last column

```
array([[[ 7, 5, 93],
        [19, 4, 69],
        [62, 2, 52]],

       [[ 6, 1, 65],
        [41, 9, 94],
        [39, 4, 49]]])
```

The desired output is:

```
array([[[ 7, 5, 93, 93],
        [19, 4, 69, 69],
        [62, 2, 52, 52]],

       [[ 6, 1, 65, 65],
        [41, 9, 94, 94],
        [39, 4, 49, 49]]])
```

Is there a clever way of doing this?

Answer (score 2):

You could concatenate along the last axis as follows-

`numpy.concatenate([a,  numpy.expand_dims(a[:, :, -1], axis=2)], axis=2)`

Answer (score 1):

There is a built-in numpy function for this purpose:

```
np.insert(x,-1,x[...,-1],-1)
```

output:

```
array([[[ 7,  5, 93, 93],
        [19,  4, 69, 69],
        [62,  2, 52, 52]],

       [[ 6,  1, 65, 65],
        [41,  9, 94, 94],
        [39,  4, 49, 49]]])
```